# Magento: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_IN

Tags: mysql, magento

I have installed Magento 1.9.0.1 and I am live since 1 month.
The first order of a Client worked without Problem. 
But now following error message appears when the order should be processed "There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later."

Log file says:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '100000001' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID'' in /home/www/web81/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

I have read a lot of threads and also used Google but could not find a solution.
I am a beginner and the shop should work tomorrow again :-(
I very much appreciate your help!

Thanks a lot for your help & best regards

Answer (score 9):

You can try following.

In `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php`

Search for isOrderIncrementIdUsed method

In that method,

replace

`$bind      = array(':increment_id' => (int)$orderIncrementId);`

with

`$bind      = array(':increment_id' => $orderIncrementId);`

------------------------------------------------------------        OR-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Go to admin->sales-> orders and look up the highest order number (for each store view!)

Then look at your database. In the table eav_entity_type you will find all entity types listed. The one of interest to change is where the order number starts, ie. order sales/order. Remember the entity_type_id.

Next go to the table eav_entity_store. Look up the entity_type_id. Now you can change the value of increment_last_id to your last actual order number. (That is, if you wanted to have your next orderId to be 15000 set increment_last_id to 14999.)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I have made a step Forward. When I put the increment_last_id to 2 manually via phpmyadmin, then I can process a second order via the shop. But after this second order, magento puts  increment_last_id automatically back to 1, so that I get the same error message again. Why does magento put increment_last_id to 1? Thanks for help!

Comment: I also noted, that the type of increment_last_id is varchar(1). Is this right? thanks.

Comment: increment_last_id should be varchar(50)

Comment: It is bad practice to edit the Magento core.  This fix has been turned into an extension here: https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AlphaIncrement

Comment: The first part do not worked for me, moreover you should recommend override the core file instead of editing it. But incrementing the value of increment_last_id with the value of the last command works fine. Saved me a lot of time and problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution. This would definitely help you.

The order number **100000001** (i.e. increment ID or **increment_id**) already exists in your order table, **sales_flat_order**, and it's failing the order save when someone checks out because **increment_ids** must be unique.

First, verify that you have these order numbers you see in the error messages are indeed already present in the **sales_flat_order.increment** column. Then, you need to modify the **eav_entity_store.increment_id** value(s), so that new increment IDs will never overlap with your the already existing order numbers.

Check the maximum value in **sales_flat_order.increment_id**, and update **eav_entity_store.increment_id** with a value greater than that.

Comment: This solution actually helped me. For some reason my eav increment entity was out of sync...

Answer (score 0):

I quite liked the answer given by Empiro Technologies.  I used that answer as inspiration but took a different approach: in my case I had migrated sales_* tables from new database to old copy of database.  However I had missed the eav_entity_store table.  So I simply updated all of the rows across in that one table, from database to database.  That worked fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had been spending quite a bit of time trying to diagnose the same error I had, I couldn't submit orders through paypal with one store view but I could with my other views. After viewing this post I realized that my increment_last_id was the culprit! I just recently imported old customer info/orders from oscommerce->magento using cart2cart and it placed all my orders into my default store view without updating the increment_last_id. After updating that int to the last imported order number I could place orders again!

Answer (score 0):

first check into **sales_flat_order** table maximum **increment_id**  and  change into **eav_entity_store** table **increment_last_id** column by incrementing 1 for example your **sales_flat_order** table maximum **increment_id is 100000001** and change **eav_entity_store** table **increment_last_id is  100000002**